# Is there a direct repo for various Android Build Numbers' update.zip

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, rom

I am looking to wipe my phone. I have a motorola droid currently running one of the first Nexus One 2.2 builds (no mod) that could be rooted to the droid. [I tried downloading a version of Froyo](http://phandroid.com/2010/08/03/manually-update-your-motorola-droid-to-froyo/) and using sprecovery to update using the update.zip method; however it wouldn't pick up on there being an update.zip to use, and it would not allow me to specify which file to use (since it wasn't in .tar format; ie not a backup).

According to phandroid (and no anger in the comment section), the two versions I downloaded should have worked. I did not MD5 all three copies, but downloading three copies and not having one of them work due to corruption seems unlikely considering nandroid spits out corrupted copies.

Anyway, I did a factory reset/wipe and I am back to the basic install of the 2.2 build I started with. However, I want to implement the official motorola droid version (either FR22* or FR33*). I would be willing to put up a ROM (likely CM6).

- Where can I download this from?
- What did I do wrong?
- Should I use a .tar ROM or a .tgz instead?

Comment: As a follow up, ROM manager is fantastic. It basically provided the functionality I was looking for in various stock builds as well as the bonus of having different modified builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some questions, and hopefully some answers:

1. So you are currently rooted, running one of the earlier leaks of Froyo for the Droid?
2. You are willing to switch to a mod CM6?
3. Or do you want to go back to plain vanilla stock without root?

If you are currently rooted and willing to try out a mod like CM6, then go to the Market and downlaod ROM Manager.  **Make a Nandroid backup of your phone before you do anything**.  Then download and install CM6 via "Download Rom" -> CyanogenMod.  You want 6.0, not the RC version.  When you download and install it, make sure you include Google Apps and wipe your data and cache.

If you are wanting to go back to plain vanilla stock, be noted that **apps like EasyRoot (one click root access) will not work for the latest version of Froyo for the Droid.**  You'll have to downgrade to 2.1 to get root access back if you go this route.

With that said, if you are rooted, go get ROM Manager.  Under Download Rom are "Stock Images".  One of those options is 2.2 FRG01B with the option of root/unrooted.  This should put you on the right path of plain vanilla stock.

Hope this helps, let me know if I misunderstood you and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Thanks much; im playing around with the different ROMs now. Tried CM6, but the google apps zip was corrupted so I decided to go after a stock image. Downloading it now...